# Something that takes advices (Technical)

Tags: expressions, nouns

I have a technical background on this question, so it has a bit of an abstraction. I have a component that can advise another component.

The question is about the component, which is able to take an advice. Is it legit if I call this component `Advisable`? Is this really abstractly describing something that is able to take advice?

Comment: 'Master ... slave' is an accepted metaphorical usage; you need to describe what you mean by one component 'advising' another. Advice can be weighed by the recipient (normally sentient of course), who may then choose whether or not to take it on board.

Comment: Read about feedback loops and circuits.

Comment: *advisable*......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Advisable" generally means "desirable," which makes it an inadvisable adjective.

Consider a hyphenated adjective such as "advice-accepting" or "advice-responsive."

Comment: I think this is actually the best solution to my problem, as the word `advice` should appear. This way, one can see directly the correlation between an advice and a component which can take advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could say, "***the consulted component***"

> **consult**
> [kuh n-suhlt]
> verb (used without object)
>
> 1. to consider or deliberate; take counsel; confer (usually followed by with).
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/consulted)

Answer (score 0):

"The advising component informs the advised component"

Answer (score 0):

You might try **receptor**. It is used in other technical fields, like these examples show:

> Sensory receptor, in physiology, any structure which, on receiving environmental stimuli, produces an informative nerve impulse
>
> Cell surface receptor, a receptor on the outer surface of a cell membrane, that takes part in communication between the cell and the outside world
>
> Nuclear receptor, a receptor found within cells that is responsible for sensing steroid and thyroid hormones and certain other molecules ([Wikipedia - Receptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptor))

A receptor receives inputs (advise) from external sources for its own internal use.

This is also consistent with your interest in its "taking advice", as the word *receptive* is defined as:

> willing or inclined to receive suggestions, offers, etc., with favor:
> a receptive listener. ([Dictionary.com #3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/receptive))